# MapBox stop location when leaving UIControllerView

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, mapbox

I use MapBox with iOS. When I create an instance in a UIViewController, when I quit this controller, Location continue to process in background.
Someone have a solution to stop location process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to some recent memory leaks that were fixed in the `develop` branch of the SDK. It was unintentionally keeping `RMMapView` instances around, which have a `CLLocationManager` instance associated for user location and heading tracking.